# In House Distribution issue with distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, profile, software-distribution

My first question here, and I have tried everything and googled like hell and couldn't find an answer to this issue.

So I have a client for whom I have to make an iOS distribution via in House distribution system (they don't want their app on the store but will use it in corporate use with over 20 devices, so the AdHoc UDID system is out of the question).

Now, the client has given me Admin roles on their Enterprise account and I have done the following:

1. Downloaded the production certificate
2. Installed the .p12 file from the client on my keychain
3. Created the app id
4. Created the provisioning profile and downloaded it too

Now, I do manage to archive the app and install it on my device, but then the app crashes like right after the splash screen. It is to my understanding that there is an issue with the production certificate, and I am clueless. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested your application in release mode ?

Comment: I don't think that it is due to the certificate... if this would be the case, I believe app would not even install on device

Comment: Before this I used my company's AdHoc list to pre-test the app on several devices, which worked fine.

Comment: Check the device console output for error messages after the installation or startup fails.

Comment: How can I do that if I am installing an .ipa file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I have managed to solve this little issue. The main problem was not the .p12 but the bundle ID itself. Since most of the times I was getting an error that the bundle ID was not matched with the provided provisioning profile. So what I did is:

1. Edited the app id on the Apple Dev Site from an old name, i.e. **com.potato.PotatoApp into com.lemon.PotatoApp** (the main reason I had to do this is cuz' my default ID is my company's ID, and in this scenario I had to use the client's Apple Dev Account, and thus the ID itself.
2. Edited the provisioning profile by selecting the newly edited app id, and then changing the name from "**PotatoApp**" to "**PotatoApp inHouse**"
3. Downloaded the newly edited profile.
4. On the Debug settings, this was the corresponding list:
       -Provisioning profile (debug & release): "**PotatoApp inHouse**"
       -Code signing identity (debug & release): "**iPhone distribution: Lemon Company Ltd.**"

Also on the team list changed from "**Potato Company Ltd.**" to "**Lemon Company Ltd.**", after that a simple Archive and the build was created without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

An enterprise-signed app won't allow a debug connection. if you want install app in device, you should create archive .ipa and install.

for debug app in device you need to signed app using AdHoc provisional profile of individual developer account.

Comment: Um...I did, I think I mentioned it in my original question. "Now, I do manage to archive the app and install it on my device, but then the app crashes like right after the splash screen..."